# Bash echo 3 variable (2 translate, 1 as text) problem

Tags: bash, variables

I made a bash script to generate a vhost file for my apache.

The problem is:

I have 3 variables in it.

2 are bash variables, defined in the .sh, and I want them to be expanded.

1 is `APACHE_LOG_DIR` variable and of course, I want it to be as literal text to be interpreted after.

I have tried

```
echo "$var1 $var2 $var3" -> all expanded
echo '$var1 $var2 $var3' -> all not expanded

echo "
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/$client-$version-error.log
" >> ./myfile
```

I want `$APACHE_LOG_DIR` to be literal text, 
`$client` `$version` to be expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
echo '$var1 '"$var2 $var3"
```

or

```
echo "\$var1 $var2 $var3"
```

Comment: Good for you figuring out what he meant. Now that I understand, I've edited the question to say it more clearly.

Comment: Thanks so much ! the \ before $var1 worked perfectly well